# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, cyclic

I have built an Ecommerce Application but when i tried to deploy it on cyclic it is showing me the above error . [This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtaIZ.png) and this is my server side code ->

[server side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdoaM.png)

As you can see in the folder structure the index.html file do exist in the build folder but why it showing this error ? Thank You

I have tried searching on the internet but i found no solid solution related to this error .

Comment: Do not add links to your post, paste the code snippets here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.